# AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'swipe'

Tags: python, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gesture-recognition

I got the following error: `AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'swipe'` for the last part of the code and error: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unknown mobile command "swipeGesture". Only shell,execEmuConsoleCommand,scrollBackTo,scroll,viewportScreenshot,deepLink,startLogsBroadcast,stopLogsBroadcast,acceptAlert,dismissAlert,batteryInfo,deviceInfo,getDeviceTime,changePermissions,getPermissions,performEditorAction,startScreenStreaming,stopScreenStreaming,getNotifications,listSms,type,sensorSet,deleteFile,startService,stopService commands are supported.` for the first part of the code.

I am not sure how to make the selenium webdriver to swipe a banner that has auto rotation set at every 5 seconds.

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance.

The attributes of the banner: [image]

My try-out code:

````
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'com.project.PROJECTNAME:id/bannersRecyclerView')))
driver.execute_script('mobile: swipeGesture', {'elementId': 'com.project.PROJECTNAME:id/bannersRecyclerView', 'direction': 'left'})

or


element.swipe()```
````

Comment: You seem to be trying to use Selenium WebDriver with a mobile app. That won't work... that's why swipe is not available. You should be using Appium.

Comment: Hey @JeffC 
I tried.. I failed. It doesn't work